# Is it possible to have more than 76 strength?

Tags: xenonauts

It seems that soldiers do not advance the strength attribute past 76 points.
The other attributes seemed to be capped at 100, though I could not get Reflexes or Bravery past 70 just yet.

When using heavy armor and new weapons I would like to have a bit more strength to carry all the stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the xenonauts.wikia.com it says, on the [Predator armor page](http://xenonauts.wikia.com/wiki/Predator):

> Soldiers using it do not level up strength, most likely due to how the armour buffs the unit's strength stat to 100.